# How to get client certificate in a Java HttpsServer implementation for a webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, certificate, httpserver

I wrote a Web Service server using Sun Ws implementation and I used a HttpsServer for publication (TLS mutual authentication).

```
        httpServer=HttpsServer.create(...);
        ssl=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ...
        ssl.init(keyFactory.getKeyManagers(),trustFactory.getTrustManagers(),new SecureRandom());
        configurator=new HttpsConfigurator(ssl) {
           public void configure (HttpsParameters params) 
           {
               SSLContext context; 
               SSLParameters sslparams;

               context=getSSLContext();
               sslparams=context.getDefaultSSLParameters();
               sslparams.setNeedClientAuth(true);
               params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
           }
       }; 
       ((HttpsServer)httpServer).setHttpsConfigurator(configurator);
       ...
       endPoint=getSunWsProvider().createEndPoint(...);
       httpContext=httpServer.createContext(...);
       endPoint.publish(httpContext);
       httpServer.start();
       ...
```

Everything works fine. When the implementation of the server side of the Web Service is executed by a client, I would like to know which client is executing the code (to manage rights). Knowing that each client gets its own certificate, how can I get the client certificate used for the TLS negociation before the Web Service call ? (I would prefer to find a solution based on the client certificate analysis instead of adding an identification information to each Web Service call).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your web-service implemented as a Servlet within "Sun Ws implementation"? If so, what does `getUserPrincipal()` give? (It's in [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).)

Comment: In the web service implementation ...  
  
    @Resource  
    WebServcieContext wsctx;

Comment: @martijno
In the web service implementation ...  
  
    WebServcieContext wsctx;
    MessageContext mctx=wsctx.getMessageContext();
    mctx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT) ... is null
    mctx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST) ... is null

and wsctx.getUserPrincipal() is null.

Answer (score 3):

in your handler you get not the `HttpExchange` instance but the instance of its subclass `HttpsExchange` that has the extra method:

> abstract [SSLSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html?is-external=true) getSSLSession();

Among many other things an SSLSession exposes peer identity

Answer (score -3):

`getUserPrincipal()` gives you the certificate in `httpservletrequest`.

Comment: No it doesn't. It gives you a Principal.